# In which project should I put the Windsor installers?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I need to add a worker role for long running tasks to my current web project using `Castle` and `Nhibernate`.

Currently many of my services are installed in `DomainModel` as `PerWebRequest`. I need to use some of those in my `Worker`, which cannot use `PerWebRequest`, so I need them to be `Transient`.

> Where is the best place to put the installers?

Should I register the services in `DomainModel` or in `Web` and `Worker` with the appropriate `LifeStyle` for each?

For example NHibernate is PerWebRequest for Web but not for Worker. Since many services inside DomainModel has dependencies on ISession it doesn't seem right to require Web or Worker assembly to register it "for" DomainModel.

My solution is organized in three projects like this:

```
DomainModel
- DAO, shared services etc.

Web
- Models and presentation

Worker (new)
- Long running background tasks
```

Comment: What about new project "Common"?

Comment: @sll Yes but how does "Common" know which LifeStyle it should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like do not have components/layers "container aware". My choice is always for the entry point project (mvc, windows form, wpf, windows service...)